# is there a way to print Graphical character in CPP?

Tags: c++, unicode

I want to print ' █ ' and ▒ to the console.

```
char i=177; char f=219; // ASCII for the Graphic char
 
std::cout<<i<<f;
```

I've tried using `wchar_t` and `std::wcout` but they aren't working. It just prints nothing or '?' or random symbols only.

**Q1**- Is there another way to do it ?
In  Visual studio it tells me to change the Unicode.

And **Q2**- when I use `printf` in Cpp it prints it . Why?

Comment: Which terminal are you running your program in?

Comment: Command Prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the following code snippet on my Arch-Linux machine and it works perfectly fine. I get the `full block character` and the `medium shade character` as I expect.

The `std::locale::global`-function is used to set the *global locale* for the entire C++ program. The global locale affects various aspects of program behavior related to localization, such as **character encoding**, number formatting, and date/time representations.

In the context of setting console output to support Unicode characters, calling `std::locale::global` with the appropriate locale can help ensure that the console is set up to handle Unicode encoding correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    wchar_t i = L'\u2588';  // Unicode for full block character '█'
    wchar_t f = L'\u2592';  // Unicode for medium shade character '▒'

    std::wcout << i << f << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned above. This works for me on Linux. Since you use CMD and  Windows, I can't be sure if it'll work for you as well!

**EDIT:** If it doesn't work on your end, try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp#syntax

Comment: Yep , Now it works . Previously it worked in VS Code Only . Thanks a lot.